# Magmi import with product attributes not showing price

Tags: magento, import, magmi

I have made a product import using Magmi with no errors on the import side.

Every product is a simple product that has 2 attributes of type checkbox that adds some options and increases the price in a manner that looks a little like this:

Product price 50,00

[ ] add packaging +1,50

[ ] add custom note +1,75

After this everything looks good except for the fact that the price is not shown in the page. I have checked for a price mapping and it is deactivated so this is not the issue.

Another strange behavior is that if I open in magento admin any product and save it (without changing anything at all) it is working correctly.

I have also tried a bulk attribute change from magento administration and after that saving all products at once bu it proved not to work.

Reindexing and cache building did not prove to solve the problem either.

Magento is 1.6.2.0 Community edition.

Comment: Post a sample of the CSV you are importing.

Comment: Here is a sample https://mega.co.nz/#!FhV2jD6Z!Gsl-kyXzR8PcNbc9WXsWnEX3gKofMYPk5k7TQSG2_vQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is incorrect data in your price column.

If you look in your CSV, you have date values in your price column, which are being imported into Magento.  Magento's core pricing Model doesn't understand this format, and therefore doesn't display the price.  When you re-save the product, the save method strips out and formats the data to the correct price format, which is why it appears after you save.

[image: Price Column]

Comment: I have updated the prices, cleaned the DB and still the problem persists.

Comment: Strip down your CSV to the basic, essential columns and work your way up.  Remove all columns except for the required ones (SKU, price, name, attribute set etc).  Add back in the columns one by one until the problem reappears.  Your CSV data is not correct, which is causing these issues you are experiencing.

Comment: Ok. I will do that and let you know what was the problem.